# How to get tweets from several users with keywords using Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm looking to gather all tweets by companies that contain keywords using Tweepy. I was able to download all tweets containing keywords using the below code. However, I don't know how to search for specific users.

```
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
# your Twitter API key and API secret
my_api_key = "MINE"
my_api_secret = "MINE"
# authenticate
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(my_api_key, my_api_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_query = "#blm OR blm -filter:retweets"

# get tweets from the API
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_query,
              lang="en",
              since="2020-05-24",
              until="2020-12-01",
              exclude_replies=False,
                   tweet_mode='extended').items()


# store the API responses in a list
tweets_copy = []
for tweet in tweets:
    tweets_copy.append(tweet)
    
print("Total Tweets fetched:", len(tweets_copy))
```

Now I'd like to get tweets from specific users: Apple, Microsoft, Netflix, etc. When I added `#id="Apple"` to the code above, it did not return the desired result. From searching online, I know that one can get all tweets from specific users using below code:

```
api.user_timeline("Apple", tweet_mode = 'extended', count=200)
```

However, I could not figure out a way to integrate the two together. Your help is appreciated!